# ANT Installation - Receiving "Access is denied." Error

Tags: java, windows, ant, windows-xp

I have copied over the apache ant directory in to my D:\ drive on my PC. Running Windows XP, by the way. I have set the following environment variables below...

`ANT_HOME` = `D:\apache-ant-1.8.2`

`JAVA_HOME` = `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43`

`%ANT_HOME%\bin` added to `Path` variable

When I run `ant -version` or `ant` on the console, I receive the following error

`Access is denied.`

So now I am at a stand still. I have tried copying over the ant directory to the C:\ drive, changing the corresponding variable, and I get the same error. I have tried adding `JAVA_HOME` to my `Path` variable, and I still get the same error. I have tried switching to the D:\ drive, and again, the same error.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This problem may relate to the JAVA_HOME variable. Make sure set ANT_HOME, PATH, JAVA_HOME env variables and try again.